# Historical classroom data and grades

Tags: google-classroom

Looking at the data stored for classes and students in classes I see no attributes that provide a year or dates for the class.
Does this mean that Google Classroom cannot store historical data for class/student grades and allow listings of all a students classes over their time at a school?

Looked at Json data for the relevant objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google classroom is behind a paywall so I can't immediately look at the UI.
Normally I can look at the data model for a system and tell what CAN be done easily rather than what the UI supports.
 When I look at the json descriptions of the data google classroom api supports I do not see data for the year a class occurred. 
That implies that Google does not support historical data, but I understand I might be missing something.
So, I am asking the question of anyone who has worked with the data .What am I missing?